# Create an additional table or create a new Database

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I have a choice of either creating a new SqLite Database or add another table to existing Database which is assessed via a Content provider.

Which choice is better in terms of 1) CPU usage 2)Memory 3)Processing Time 4)Programming best practices?

I re-read faq for this question and believe this question belongs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new table data is logically connected with all the other data you already have, next table looks the right choice. As for "optimizations" aspect you are trying to consider - don't. It is rather irrelevant.